# Android: Update database table

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have an app with the SQlite DB inside and MySQL DB on the server.

---

**SQLite:**

Table 1: some columns

Table 2: some columns

**MySQL:**

The same tables and columns.

---

I want to ask you: *Is it possible and is it the proper way for creating such functionality, like*:

User starts the app and there is two buttons <=> activities (Activity 1 & Activity 2)

Activity 1: ListView with data from Table 1

Activity 2: ListView with data from Table 2

For example, user chooses Activity 1. The application proposes to user to update the data. If he/she agrees, the app makes connection with the server and updates SQlite DB Table 1 with data from MySQL DB Table 1.

The same is for Activity 2, but now, the data will be downloaded from Table 2.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

What you describe is perfectly fine, I suggest creating a content provider to wrap your sqlite db. That way you can take advantage of a lot of framework functions to get your data.

You will have to probably implment CursorAdapter to populate data inside a listView.

Check out this link to know more about COntentProviders and Sqlite
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

Check out this link to know more about cursoradapters

http://blog.cluepusher.dk/2009/11/16/creating-a-custom-cursoradapter-for-android/

Check out this Google I/O to check out the architecture you could implement on your app

http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/developing-RESTful-android-apps.html

Comment: Thanks! it's clear. Maybe I didn't describe my question propelry, but the main purpose is how to update exactly one table per one request to the sever. The app requests data from Table 1 and then updates it's SQLite DB Table 1 with this data.